# ORMLite + H2 error: "No database files have been found in directory..."

Tags: java, eclipse, h2, ormlite

I am very new to working with databases in Java.  I am running an eclipse project that implements ORMLite over H2.

The problem is that as long as I have just my test project my code works fine.  That is to say, my code creates a new database file and populates it with tables which then get data inserted into them.

But, when I import another project into my work-space I get the following message on the console whenever I try to run ANY project:

```
No database files have been found in directory C:\Users\crimsonsky\workspace\Common
```

This isn't an error, but it does terminate the run of the code before any of my code had a chance to run.

I'm guessing this is some sort of configuration problem but I can't resolve it.
can anyone help?  I've tried looking for the message in the documentation of both H2 and ORMLite but found no reference to it.

Comment: Is there a full exception?  If so can you post at least a couple of lines from it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is something wrong in your project entry point (AKA public static void main(string[] args)). The project is trying to start from one of the h2 classes. I would recheck the import process. Make sure you are running everything from where you wanted

Comment: thx, it was trying to run it from on of the refrenced jar files.